# Confusion about implementing traits in a tricky lifetimes setup

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

Suppose, I want to do the following - I want to have a struct, which holds 2 things: data and another struct, which references this data and implements a trait, which forces it to have method `new`, which takes a reference to this data.

Let's first focus on this second struct: since it holds a reference, we also need to specify lifetimes(even if we don't, let's do it anyway for educational purposes), so we get something like this, when creating it:

```rust
trait Trait<'a> {
    fn new(data_ref: &'a Data) -> Self; 
}

// Struct may be large, so we don't really want to clone it.
struct Data {
    value: u8,
}

struct TraitStruct<'a> {
    data_ref: &'a Data,
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for TraitStruct<'a> {
    fn new(data_ref: &'a Data) -> Self {
        return TraitStruct {
            data_ref,
        };
    }
}
```

Now, returning to the initial struct, I want to restrict the type of struct that it holds to one, that implements our trait, so naive way to do that would look like this:

```rust
struct StructHolder<T> where
    T: Trait
{
    data: Data,
    trait_struct: T,
}

impl<T> StructHolder<T> where 
    T: Trait
{
    fn new(data: Data) -> Self {
        let trait_struct = T::new(&data);
        return StructHolder {
            data,
            trait_struct,
        }; 
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because `Trait` is generic over a lifetime, and compiler suggests using HRTB's:

```
   |
41 |     T: Trait
   |        ^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = note: for more information on higher-ranked polymorphism, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html
help: consider making the bound lifetime-generic with a new `'a` lifetime
   |
41 |     T: for<'a> Trait<'a>
   |        +++++++      ++++
help: consider making the bound lifetime-generic with a new `'a` lifetime
   |
41 |     for<'a> T: Trait<'a>
   |     +++++++         ++++
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
40 ~ struct StructHolder<'a, T> where
41 ~     T: Trait<'a>
   |
```

No problem, suggestion is straightforward and we get:

```rust
struct StructHolder<T> where
    for<'a> T: Trait<'a>
{
    trait_struct: T,
}

impl<T> StructHolder<T> where
    for<'a> T: Trait<'a>
{
    fn new(data: Data) -> Self {
        let trait_struct = T::new(&data);
        return StructHolder {
            data,
            trait_struct,
        };
    }
}
```

This does remove the errors, but the main problem, which led me to asking this question is what happens, when I try to call `new` on `StructHolder::<TraitStruct>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = StructHolder::<TraitStruct>::new(Data { value: 0 });
}
```

Compiler prints out the following error:

```
   |
5  | struct TraitStruct<'a> {
   | ---------------------- doesn't satisfy `TraitStruct<'_>: Trait<'a>`
...
21 | struct StructHolder<T> where
   | ---------------------- function or associated item `new` not found for this struct
...
41 |     let result = StructHolder::<TraitStruct>::new(Data { value: 0 });
   |                                               ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `StructHolder<TraitStruct<'_>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `TraitStruct<'_>: Trait<'a>`
note: the following trait must be implemented
  --> src/main.rs:1:1
   |
1  | trait Trait<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Trait` defines an item `new`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src/main.rs:1:1
   |
1  | trait Trait<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After some time thinking about it and trying things ous, I must admit, that I simply don't understand, what the error actually is. Text seems to say that `Trait` is not implemented for `TraitStruct` and that new is not found for `StructHolder<T>` and I flat out don't understand what is wrong with `impl` blocks above that leads to this error.

Don't really know how to ask a good question here, just want to understand why this happens.

Also, I think, I know how to try to fix this by wrapping the struct inside `StructHolder` in a `Box` for example, but it feels like there is a solution, which doesn't use indirection and it would be interesting to know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you promise to provide a `for<'a> T: Trait<'a>` but you only provide a `T::new(&'_ data)` = `impl Trait<'_>` borrowing from a local variable. Since `'_` doesn't outlive `'a` which could also be something like `'static` that's not allowed.

In general I think what you want isn't really possible because it would require you to hold both `Data` and `TraitStruct` in the same `struct` but since `TraitStruct` references `Data` that'd be a [self referential struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct).